# How to use Admob ad in LinearLayout?

Tags: android, admob, android-linearlayout, android-relativelayout

Hello I have made an app that has 17 activities made with `Linearlayout` . I did not know anything about Admob or how to use in android project so I made my project with `LinearLayout`. After some tutorials and YouTube videos I could not find out how to use ads with `Linearlayout`. Everybody is changing their layout to `RelativeLayout`. How can I add advertisements in my app.

Every layout file contains scroll view and other `LinearLayout` layout nested.

Advanced Thank You

Comment: You need to precise your problem best by showing what you've done in your code so far. That's way better to help you improving the code. No matter whether it's a `LinearLayout` or a `RelativeLayout` the ad is set up the same way in general

Answer (score 0, accepted):

from the way you described it, I suppose you're using `Banners`, if not then you don't need to alter your layout because all the other ad types are add by code in java. Regarding banner ads you can put your `linearLayout` insead of a `constraintLayout` and then you can add the `BannerAd` above your `linearLayout`, that way you won't have to change the layout very much.

Answer (score 0):

I was just want to place ads on the top of scrollview so there is no need to change layout . Just make a linear layout with horizontal or vertical orientation place you adView in That and the test ad will show there . It is really simple . I stupidly ask this question . Sorry for that .